# Uniqueness of the Frobenius automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of algebraic number fields with rings of integers $\mathcal{O}_L$ and $\mathcal{O}_K$ respectively.

Let $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ be a prime ideal and $\mathfrak{P} \subset \mathcal{O}_L$ a prime above $\mathfrak{p}$.

It can be shown that there exists an automorphism $\varphi_{\mathfrak{P}} \in \textrm{Gal}(L/K)$ satisfying

$$
\varphi_{\mathfrak{P}}(x) \equiv x^q\ (\textrm{mod}\ \mathfrak{P}) \qquad \forall x \in \mathcal{O}_L \tag{1},
$$
where $q:=\lvert \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p} \rvert$.

This is the Frobenius automorphism of $L/K$ corresponding to the prime $\mathfrak{P}$.

I want to show that the element in $\textrm{Gal}(L/K)$ satisfying $(1)$ is unique.

My idea was to assume that $\sigma, \tau \in \textrm{Gal}(L/K)$ satisfy $(1)$, then define $\upsilon:=\sigma^{-1}\circ \tau$, so that

$$
\upsilon(x) \equiv x\ (\textrm{mod}\ \mathfrak{P})\qquad \forall x \in \mathcal{O}_L. \tag{2}
$$
Or in other words:

$$
\mathfrak{P} \mid \upsilon(x)-x \qquad \forall x \in \mathcal{O}_L. \tag{3}
$$
Then somehow deduce from (3) that

$$
\mathfrak{P} \mid \upsilon(x)-x \qquad \forall x \in L, \tag{4}
$$
from which one would conclude that
$$
\upsilon(x)-x = 0 \qquad \forall x \in L, \tag{5}
$$

and thus find that $\upsilon = \textrm{Id} \in \textrm{Gal}(L/K)$, and hence $\sigma = \tau$.

But as I am sure you will agree, the above is more reminiscent of wishful thinking than actual mathematics.

Does anyone know if there is a standard "book proof" of the statement, or if one might prove it along lines similar to the above?

Many thanks.

Comment: @Mathmo123 They should all be $L$. Apologies. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is *almost* correct. The problem is that the fact that you are trying to prove is false: the Frobenius element need not be unique! For example, in the extension $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb Q$, if $\mathfrak p = (2)$ and $\mathfrak P = (\sqrt 2)$, then both elements of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb Q)$ are Frobenius elements. However, if $\mathfrak P/\mathfrak p$ is unramified, then the Frobenius element will be unique and your argument is a part of the proof.

Let $D=D_{\mathfrak {P/p}} = \{\sigma\in \mathrm{Gal}(L/K):\sigma(\mathfrak P)= \mathfrak P\}$ be the *decomposition group*. If $\sigma \in  D$, then $\sigma$ acts on $\mathcal O_L$ and fixes $\mathfrak P$, so descends to an automorphism of $\mathcal O_L/\mathfrak P$. In this way, we get a homomorphism
$$D_{\mathfrak{P/p}}\to \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb F_\mathfrak P/\mathbb F_{\mathfrak p}).$$

This map is surjective, and any element in the preimage of the Frobenius element of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb F_\mathfrak P/\mathbb F_{\mathfrak p})$ is a Frobenius element in $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$.

The kernel of this isomorphism, called the *inertia group* is
$$I=I_{\mathfrak{P/p}} = \{\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(L/K) : \sigma(x) = x\pmod {\mathfrak P}\; \forall x\in\mathcal O_L\}.$$
Note that this group being trivial is exactly what you need to be able to deduce $(5)$ from $(4)$ in your sketch proof.

However, the inertia group need not be trivial: its order is exactly $e(\mathfrak {P/p})$, the ramification index of $\mathfrak{P/p}$. Hence, the Frobenius element is unique if and only if $\mathfrak{P/p}$ is unramified.

Comment: Very good. You are right, I should have specified that the prime $\mathfrak{p}$ is unramified over $\mathcal{O_L$.
So one uses the fact that the inertia subgroup is trivial to deduce (5) from (4).
But my main scruple is how one goes from (3) to (4).

Comment: Ah I see. But I think you only need $\mathfrak P\mid v(x) - x$ for $x\in\mathcal O_L$, right?

Comment: You're saying that if we know that the inertia subgroup is trivial, then we can deduce (5) directly from (3)? I will have to think about that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the inertia group is trivial, then you deduce that $v(x) = x$ for all $x\in \mathcal O_L$. But then $v(x) = x$ for all $x\in L$ as well.

Comment: If an automorphism behaves like the identity on $\mathcal{O}_L \subset L$, must it necessarily be the identity? I suppose it would be sufficient to show that no intermediate field $K \subseteq M \subseteq L$ contains $\mathcal{O}_L$.

Comment: Any automorphism is completely determined by its action on any $\mathbb Q$-basis of $L$! Alternatively, every element of $L$ is a quotient of elements of $\mathcal O_L$. Either way, the action on $\mathcal O_L$ determines the whole automorphism.

Comment: Every element in $L$ can be expressed as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of elements in $\mathcal{O}_L$? How very strange that I was unaware of this fact.

Comment: You were aware of it in a different form I'm sure! By the primitive element theorem, you can write $L = \mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and you can always engineer that $\alpha\in\mathcal O_L$ (e.g. by multiplying by the norm of the denominator). Then $1, \alpha, \alpha^2,\ldots$ is a $\mathbb Q$-basis of $L$ consisting of elements of $\mathcal O_L$.